# Dependencies in a library module

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I am building a library in Android Studio which has multiple Gradle dependencies such as the estimote and firebase sdk. When I export the library as an aar and then import it to a sample project, I get a run time error:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/estimote/sdk/BeaconManager;
                                                                                   at com.mgenio.sdk.BeaconSDK.init(BeaconSDK.java:87)
                                                                                   at com.mgenio.sdk.BeaconSDK.checkSDK(BeaconSDK.java:214)
                                                                                   at com.mgenio.sdk.BeaconSDK.access$800(BeaconSDK.java:33)
                                                                                   at com.mgenio.sdk.BeaconSDK$3.onResponse(BeaconSDK.java:186)
                                                                                   at com.mgenio.sdk.BeaconSDK$3.onResponse(BeaconSDK.java:182)
                                                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                                   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mgenio.smartscansample-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mgenio.smartscansample-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

Is there a special way to export my aar library so it includes these external dependencies? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use the library in one or in multiple projects?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue some months ago, if you're publishing your library in a repository, then you have to add an xml or another kind of file that contains the dependencies your library have.

And if you need yo use any class of those dependencies, when you compile your library in the gradle file in your app module, you have to add `transitive=true` to have access to this classes or resources like this

```
compile('mx.segundamano.doubleseekbarview'){
    transitive=true
}
```

**EDIT**

If you're publishing to Bintray - Maven repository, add this lines to your gradle file at the same level where your `bintray` configuration is

```
task generateSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives generateSourcesJar
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of the correct xml file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a special way to export my aar library so it includes these external dependencies?

No

---

Exept you deploy your aar into a maven or ivy repository.

Comment: how is then place where you put your aar of any relevance?

Answer (score 0):

These aar dependency have some inbuild functionality in itself such as ic-launcher icon , image,logo, animation and much more.
Dhamija Dependency is one of them. such as :-

```
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.8@aar
```

**but you can use a best commercial dependency inside aar** Remove above dependency and use this :

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
```

hope this will resolve your issue !

Answer (score -1):

You just add the same dependencies to your sample project and let Gradle take care of it.